# Is it possible to have a side menu inside a tab view with Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Right now I'm struggling with one thing. I'm trying to insert a side menu navigation inside a specific tab view. The thing is that I am unable to launch the view as pretended.

In the tab view, I'm calling the view like this:

```
<ion-tab title="Market" class="ion-custom-tab" icon-off="ion-bag" icon-on="ion-bag" badge="badgeNumber" ng-click="ChangeView('tab.market.deals');">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

and in the app.init I wrote this:

```
$stateProvider
    // Message State
    // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'angular/app/thirdparty/tabs.html'
    })

    .state("tab.profile", {
        url: "/profile",
        views: {
            'tab-others': {
                templateUrl: "angular/app/definitions/profile/profile.template.html"
            }
        }
    })
    .state("tab.market", {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/market",
        templateUrl: 'angular/app/market/market.html',
        controller: 'angular/app/market/market.controller.js'
    })
    .state("tab.market.deals", {
        url: "/market/deals",
        views: {
            'tab-market': {
                templateUrl: "angular/app/market/deals/deals.html"
            }
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please create a plnkr/fiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: your menu would be inside tab.market's market.html right?

Comment: Yes that is my objective

Comment: @lin i'm sorry I cant right now, but when i get home ill try to assemble a sample project with the problem